# What's the difference between compromise and corruption in MPC?

Tags: multiparty-computation

What is the difference between `corruption` and `compromise`? Are `Compromising a user` and `corrupting a user` same?

Comment: Do you have specific papers/slides that you're looking at?

Comment: Many crypto-related papers include both terms. One of the examples is https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/464.pdf, where the both term coexist